# What is the correct way of using SpeechRecognition's AudioData function?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, pyaudio, google-speech-api

I am trying to use sceech_recognition to translate my recorded audio data to text and so far I am able to successfully translate the recorded audio using a `.wav` . I am using `pyaudio` to record audio to a `.wav` file. Since `pyaudio` creates an audio stream, instead of writing it to a file and then using the file in speech_recognition, I want to translate the audio stream directly. Below is the implementation which should take the audio stream and then use `sr.AudioData` function and translate the audio.

```
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = get_nonexistant_path("voice.wav")

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data) #appending all the intermediate streams to a list

print("* done recording")

r = sr.Recognizer()

audio_bytes = b''.join(frames) #converting list to a byte object 
audio_source = sr.AudioData(audio_bytes, RATE, CHANNELS)

try:
    print('Trying to convert')
    text = r.recognize_google(audio_data=audio_source, language='en-US', show_all=True)
    print(text)

except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Could not understand")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

Now, every time I run this code, I get an empty list as output.

```
* recording
* done recording
Trying to convert
[]
```

Since I am also saving the audio stream to a `.wav` file for debugging purpose, when I use the same`.wav` file I get the correct translation.

```
You said "Google speech"
{'alternative': [{'transcript': 'Google speech', 'confidence': 0.98762912}], 'final': True}
```

Can someone please tell me what is going wrong here.

Comment: How did you end up doing this ?